# Trying to install pycharm with snap gives error: error: snap "pycharm-community" not found

Tags: pycharm

I try to install pycharm with the command:

`sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`

I get the error:

`error: snap "pycharm-community" not found`

If you could help me, I would appreciate it!

Comment: It's working for me with Ubuntu 16.04... Have you tried with apt-get update?

Answer (score 3):

First you have to add below mentioned repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
```

Then use theses commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pycharm
```

Answer (score -2):

Fastest and most reliable way:
Go to:

[enter link description here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html)

Go to Linux version.

Install the Toolbox App
Download the installer .exe from the Toolbox App web page.

Run the installer and follow the wizard steps.

After you run the Toolbox App, click its icon in the notification area and select which product and version you want to install.

Follow the instructions.

You are done!

Comment: Are you suggesting to run `exe` on Ubuntu?